# Как подключить уже готовую и заполненную базу данных SQLite в Android?

Tags: android, sqlite

Как подключить уже готовую и заполненную базу данных SQLite в Android?
Может кто поделиться ссылками как это сделать, в интернете полно примеров, но там на примерах только как создать во время установки и потом её наполняет сам пользователь, или старые статьи они просто не работают, мне нужно что нибудь вроде справочника уже с готовой бд.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5949629/1659629    
я этим кодом пользуюсь уже год...

Comment: хм, а что делает данный код просто копирует бд из assets в /data/data/(packagename)/databases и все?
как дальше работать с бд? (

Comment: @e1148611 дальше работать так же как, если бы вы создавали базе программно. Использовать SQLiteOpenHelper.

Answer (score 4):

Нельзя так просто обратиться к файлу базы, если он в .apk. Вам предварительно надо скопировать этот файл в "/data/data/имя_пакета/databases/".

А уже потом можно использовать эту базу в вашем  SQLiteOpenHelper'е.

Comment: > Цитата Нельзя так просто обратиться к файлу базы, если он в .apk. Вам предварительно надо скопировать этот файл в "/data/data/имя_пакета/databases/".
А уже потом можно использовать эту базу в вашем SQLiteOpenHelper'е.

А как найти эту папку? Может кто-то объяснить?

Comment: @dummyuser - надо вызвать метод `context.getDatabasePath()` - [см. документацию](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getDatabasePath(java.lang.String)). В качестве опции вы можете переопределить этот метод в своем `Activity`, так чтобы она указывала на то место куда вы положили ваш файл БД.